# Show bootstrap alert on a video tag

Tags: html

I have the following div items. the first one plays the video and the second one display the bootstrap alert. I want to display the alert on the video. Can any one help?

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  <strong>You already watched the promo for this video!</strong> Please be our premium user by activating the video package here.
</div>

<video id="video" src="/uploaded_images/{{$video->promo_video_url}}"
data-viblast-key="d784d003-60eb-46b5-b801-c534b6560036" controls style="width: 100%;">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.onplaying = function(e) {
      /*Do things here!*/
      $('#alert').show();
    }
</script>



<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="alert">
  <strong>You already watched the promo for this video!</strong> Please be our premium user by activating the video package here.
</div>

<video id="video" src="/uploaded_images/{{$video->promo_video_url}}"
data-viblast-key="d784d003-60eb-46b5-b801-c534b6560036" controls style="width: 100%;">
</video>
```

Comment: Is this possible to change the javascript alert to bootstrap alert?

Comment: Okay. but what i need is to show bootstrap alert while video is playing. can you help with that.

Comment: Yeah I did. It shows native javascript alert. what I was looking for is bootstrap alert.

Comment: I cant see it can you post it again. Thanx for the help.